# Building docker images on slaves with cache

Tags: docker, containers, dockerfile, slave

I have a continuous building system where docker images are being built after every commit. It is scalable and every build is on the separate slave. It works fine for small docker images, but for bigger ones, it takes sometimes hours to build a docker image for bigger projects, e.g. web apps. It is caused by lack of docker cache on slaves because they are dynamically created when building start

I wonder if there is some solution to share docker cache between those slave nodes? Have you ever encountered that problem?

**EDIT**

As recommended in answers I tried building with option `--cache-from`, but did not work, because every node calculates **identical layers** differently:

[image]

[Here is a link to to comparison](https://www.diffchecker.com/2jLhUbqY)

Any ideas why docker calculates identical layers differently?

Comment: One idea that I haven't tried, but I think it will work is to place `/var/lib/docker` on nfs or any kind of network storage.

Comment: Do you have your Docker trusted repository(DTR)?.Suggested approach is building the image in one machine and pushing it into DTR and for remaining slaves just pulling it.

Comment: @Taz Have you tried the solution we discussed and is it working for you?

Comment: @Akshaybarahate it didn't work. I edited my question and added explanation. Any ideas?

Comment: @Taz are you still building the images on the node?. To utilise the cache while building the image, we agreed to build the image on same machine every time. on node machine you just want to pull the latest version which you built. Are you not trying the same steps??

Comment: @Akshaybarahate my nodes are docker containers where images are built and push and after that those nose/containers are exited. Before next builds every new node starts with pulling image with `latest` tag.

Answer (score 0):

**Base principle:** *Build Once, Deploy Anywhere*.

I understand you are building the image on different salves multiple times.

How about introducing "**Image Repositories** [DTR](https://docs.docker.com/ee/dtr/) or [Docker-Hub](https://hub.docker.com/)" in middle.

1. [Build](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/build/) the image once using one worker node and [Push](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/push/) to Image Repositories.
2. [Pull](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/pull/) the image on remaining worker node.

This helps environment consistency as same image is getting used in all salves.

if you are willing to push image in docker-hub and pull back. Need to consider network latency, Before making decision.

We handled this problem with DTR, which is hosted in same network where I have other worker and pushing and pulling didn't take much time.

**DTR:** If security and image promotions can be other concerns,Then can be well handled with this approach by creating image promotion criteria.

***PS: This answer will be improved based on question clarifications***

Comment: I have private docker hub. So you suggests `docker push` and   `docker pull` +  `--cache-from` before every build, don't you?

Comment: With that https://docs.docker.com/registry/recipes/mirror/  **Furthermore, if your images are all built in-house, not using the Hub at all and relying entirely on your local registry is the simplest scenario**

Comment: regarding https://docs.docker.com/registry/recipes/mirror/, when I add my private registry to `registry-mirrors` will docker look for layers there and pull them if same layers exist in current `Dockerfile`?

Comment: I just tested in my env. I noticed even if you don't add `registry-mirrors` and just perform pull and if you have the previous version of image available.It will reuse those layers.

Comment: I know that, but my point is will layers from `registry-mirrors` be automatically used while performing `docker build` without prior `docker pull`?

Comment: I don't really think you need `registry-mirrors` now. whole idea for mirror is to avoid external internet traffic. If you have DTR (private repo) then not recommended that mirror as everything is internal in network . For `docker build`  better to perform clean build one time than multiple times. Still time take to build will be less and you can reduce the significant amount of time for your  CI job.  Again build will use previous cache only if CI uses same salve to build the image and provided docker caching still available.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/194006/discussion-between-taz-and-akshay-barahate).